# Select only child item (tree item) of treeview using change listener javafx

Tags: java, hibernate, treeview

I am creating a product list screen where products are listed by their categories. I am sucessful in doing so and I have implemented a change listener which will print the selected tree item. 
But I only want to select the product not the categories. Here is my code that I have done so far.

Thing I want to know :- How to select only the product name from list and not the category name.

```
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    Session session = null;
    TreeItem<String> CategoryrootItem = null;
    TreeItem<String> dummyRoot = new TreeItem<>();

    try {
        sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        /*Select categories from database*/
        List categoryList = session.createQuery("FROM Category").list();
        for (Iterator iterator = categoryList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Category category = (Category) iterator.next();

            CategoryrootItem = new TreeItem<>(category.getCategory_Name());
            Set productList = category.getProducts();

            //access via new for-loop
            for(Object object : productList) {
               ProductHeader productHeader = (ProductHeader) object;
               TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<>(productHeader.getProduct_Name());
               CategoryrootItem.getChildren().add(item);
            }
            dummyRoot.getChildren().add(CategoryrootItem);
        }
        treeView.setRoot(dummyRoot);
        treeView.setShowRoot(false);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out
                .println("populateSupplierList unable to create session : "
                        + e.getMessage());
    }

     treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener() {

            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue,
                    Object newValue) {

                TreeItem<String> selectedItem = (TreeItem<String>) newValue;
                System.out.println("Selected Text : " + selectedItem.getValue());
            }

          });
```

[The image gives the of the code. I want the product `kaju` to be selected but not `Dry fruits` category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lE8X.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem through logical code. I searched whether a selected `TableItem` has any children or not. If it has children items then it wont be selected, if it doesn't have child item, it will be selected. 
Those `TableItem` having child items is a category and those which doesn't have is a product.

Here is my code

```
  TreeItem<String> selectedItem = (TreeItem<String>) newValue;
    if(selectedItem.getChildren().isEmpty()){
       System.out.println("Its a product");
        }
    else{
       System.out.println("Its a category");
        }
```